# Dynamic load data on scroll

Tags: dynamic, load

I am working on a web application, where we need to show more than 20,000 rows in a single page.

What is the best way to achieve this? As per requirements, we cant use pagination.
We are looking at options like Live Scrolling in Adobe Flex..is there any other framework that helps in doing this job efficient and easy?

Comment: yeah also a few more demos, just search the subject on google.

Answer (score 2):

I found this tutorial while surfing. i think this is just what you need :)

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

cheers.